# Can't display unique react-tag-input tags when mapping data in JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, tags

I'm having trouble when mapping and rendering multiple react-tag-input components inside my Dashboard component. Each mapped value renders a unique tag, but empty tags are being displayed on all mapped values. Any idea if there's a way to solve this? Here is a codesandbox to help clarify what I mean.
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/luciomcamargo/JSON_UI

Try adding tags. They render on all the mapped values. Also when deleting with backspace all values also delete. Maybe there's some CSS workaround, or a prop I can pass to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you are keeping all tags in one place so they apply to every item. The easiest solution is to create additional js file for the item with separate tags state inside.

[Here is the working solution.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/64oqy359xk)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but if you notice your solution takes care of the tags, but makes the entire search function useless. I ended up creating my own tags. Cheers anyway.